# Change Keyboard in XCUITest/Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xctest, xcuitest

I want to change the keyboard language programatically for my XCUITests to try various different keyboards. I've tried:

```
XCUIApplication().launchArguments += ["-AppleLanguages", "(fr)"]
XCUIApplication().launchArguments += ["-AppleLocale", "fr_FR"]
```

But this only changes language and locale, but it still keeps simulator default keyboard. I know I could probably do it by going to the settings app (inside of the UITest) and just change keyboard, but I'd like to do it as an input argument or similar.

I also don't want to have all keyboard languages installed on the simulator at the same time, only the one language I choose.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "but I'd like to do it as an input argument or similar" But you cannot change the keyboard within your app that way in real life, so you cannot change the keyboard in a UI test that way. The only thing you can do in a UI test is click (and type and so on). So you need to bring up the keyboard and tap the keyboards button on the keyboard and change keyboards just like you would in real life.

Comment: If your app is _localized_ for different languages, you can use a _Test Plan_ to change the system settings for different test runs. Maybe that's what you're looking for. Watch the testing video from WWDC 2019; they give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do it in Simulator, you can access the entire macOS disk space, including Simulator support files.

Each simulator has its own setting located in

`$HOME/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SIMULATOR_ID/data/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

In this file, you can change `AppleKeyboards` programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Seems not to work for me. Once I remove or add items to the `AppleKeyboards` array and start the simulator it automatically adds a default layout. Any idea why or how to have only one keyboard layout? Using Simulator version 12.4.

Answer (score 1):

New path for .plist file to change properties of keyboard from Roman Zakharov's answer:

/Users/YOUR_USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/YOUR_SIMULATOR_ID/data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboard.preferences.plist

Simulator ID can be found from Xcode: Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators. The Identifier value is the UDID.